# Is there a way to skip an element if it does not exist on a web page with Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I am scraping numerous similar webpages, however; to get the same information lies beneath different XPATHs on some of the pages.

Here are the two XPATHs that I am tryin to alternate.

```
    city_e = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div/h4"))
        )
```

```
alternative_name_e = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='SFbizctc53fcd34ec260b1442c7bd7b4']/div/div[1]"))
        )
```

FULL CODE BELOW:

```
results = []

for i in range(6):
    links = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".SFpne a"))
        )
    links[i].click()
    time.sleep(4)


    name_e = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div/h3"))
        )
     alternative_name_e = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='SFbizctc53fcd34ec260b1442c7bd7b4']/div/div[1]"))
        )
    city_e = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div/h4"))
        )       
        
    jobTitle_e = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@itemprop='contactPoint']/div"))
        ) 
    address_e = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@itemprop='contactPoint']/address"))
        )
    cell_e = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div/a[@class='SFbizctcphn']"))
        )
    email_e = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='SFbizpne0']/div[3]/div/a"))
        )
 

    full_member_content = {
    'Member_Name': [alternative_name_e.text],
    'member_Name': [name_e.text],
    'member_City': [city_e.text],
    'member_JobTitle': [jobTitle_e.text],
    'member_Address': [address_e.text],
    'member_Cell': [cell_e.text],
    'member_Email': [email_e.text]
        }
    
    
    
    results.append(full_member_content)
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.back()
    
    
print(results)
```

Just curios if there is a try catch of an if statement that I could add to accomplish this.

**Second Challenge**: If this is an easy fix, I am also curious of whether I could re-run `city_e= WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div/h4")))` when more that one `h4` tag appears.

Thank you!

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syhlr.png)

Comment: _tryin to alternate_, __if there is a try catch of an if statement that I could add to accomplish this: What exactly you are trying to do? What is the usecase you are trying to automate?

Comment: Is this a school assignment? What's with that 'second challenge'? Are you sure it's not a separate question? What is the url you are trying to scrape?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium; following this link, https://www.showme.org/membership/membership-directory/#!directory/ord=lnm each user has a separate webpage with information about them. I am looking to retrieve that information.  

Here are two examples of the different webpages:
https://www.showme.org/membership/membership-directory/#!biz/id/53fcd34ec260b1442c7bd7b4

https://www.showme.org/membership/membership-directory/#!biz/id/53fcd354c260b1442c7bd836

Does that make any more sense?

Comment: @platipus_on_fire the "Challenge" I refer to is a roadblock for me that would be a bonus if you could offer any help. Take this link for example: https://www.showme.org/membership/membership-directory/#!biz/id/53fcd34ec260b1442c7bd7b4 My goal would be to scrape gilmore's information - the bonus would be to scrape Sid, Mark, David, etc. Let me know if that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can't look for non existance of an object. For your first question you're looking at:

Forcefully sleeping.

```
 time.sleep(4)
```

Then doing something similar to what you did with links

```
exists =EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((your selector))
```

Before doing anything check the length of exists. If it's more than 0 it is there otherwise it is the other one.

For your bonus question do the same thing with all elements located for the h4 tag and go over them one by one just like youre doing now with links